# DatabaseChangeRegistration in remote server

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11gr2

I need to set a listener in my oracle database that is triggered when an insert, delete or update occurs. For this I followed [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/dbmgmnt.htm#CHDCJFGJ) and my code was like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        OracleChangesNotification or = new OracleChangesNotification();
        or.Run();
    }

    void Run() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        OracleConnection con = CreateConnection();

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.setProperty(OracleConnection.DCN_NOTIFY_ROWIDS, "true");
        prop.setProperty(OracleConnection.DCN_QUERY_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION, "true");
        DatabaseChangeRegistration dcr = con.registerDatabaseChangeNotification(prop);

        DCNDemoListener list = new DCNDemoListener(this);
        dcr.addListener(list);

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ((OracleStatement) stmt).setDatabaseChangeRegistration(dcr);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from dept");
        while (rs.next()) {
        }
        String[] tableNames = dcr.getTables();
        for (int i = 0; i < tableNames.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(tableNames[i] + " is part of the registration.");
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();

    }

    public OracleConnection CreateConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        return (OracleConnection) DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.26.32.72:1521:orcl", "scott",
                "tiger");
    }
```

DemoListener class with event implementation

```
public class DCNDemoListener implements DatabaseChangeListener {
    OracleChangesNotification demo;

    DCNDemoListener(OracleChangesNotification dem) {
        demo = dem;
    }

    public void onDatabaseChangeNotification(DatabaseChangeEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());

    }
}
```

Oracle Listener configuration:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =

    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = orcl)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = principal)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = dg4odbc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.26.32.72)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\Administrator
```

This works well for a localhost, but when I try to do with a remote host `172.26.32.72` does not work. I know the registration is doing because when running the query `select table_name from USER_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION_REGS` returns `scott.dept` but when I do any dml operation does not fire the event. Any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that that `172.26.32.72` is listening on `1521`. Try pinging it.

Comment: Yes @shinjw , i´m sure. in fact i´m connected to oracle database right now

Comment: Post your listener.ora

Comment: @shinjw i post the listener.ora

Comment: Update to patchset https://blogs.oracle.com/db/entry/oracle_database_11g_release_2

Comment: Hi Aramillo try http://www.dadbm.com/how-to-troubleshoot-oracle-remote-database-connection/. I believe the ports are unable to communicate. Also, you can try with port 8080 i.e. (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=myhost.mydomain.com)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)
     (Session=RAW))

Answer (score 1):

You can check active listeners in the Oracle database running the following query:

```
Select * FROM USER_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION_REGS
```

I the query does not return any rows probably the database server can't access the jdbc driver listener port.

By default the Oracle JDBC driver listens at port 47632 for notifications. You will need to ensure that it is possible to connect to that port from the database server. You may need to add a rule in the firewall to accept incoming requests to that port.

This port can be changed with the NTF_LOCAL_TCP_PORT option:

```
prop.setProperty(OracleConnection.NTF_LOCAL_TCP_PORT, "15000");
```